# How to set the class method as event handler?

Tags: javascript, class

I try to write the form autocomplite as JavaScript class, but I have an error "autocomplete.requestSuggestions is not a function" in console log. How I can set the class method as event handler?

```
<script>
    class Autocomplete {
        constructor(path, queryId) {
            this.handler = new XMLHttpRequest();
            this.url = new URL(path, document.location.origin);
            this.query = document.getElementById(queryId);
        }

        requestSuggestions() {
            if(this.query.value.length >= this.query.minLength)
            {
                this.url.searchParams.set(this.query.name, this.query.value);
                this.handler.open('GET', this.url);
                this.handler.onload = this.showSuggestions;
                this.handler.responseType = 'json';
                this.handler.send();
            }
        }

        showSuggestions() {
            let response = this.handler.response;

            if(response.length > 0)
            {
            }
        }
    };
</script>
<form action="/search" autocomplete="off" method="get">
    <input data-result-empty="Nothing found" id="query" maxlength="64" minlength="3" name="query" oninput="autocomplete.requestSuggestions();" placeholder="Product search" required type="search" value="">
</form>
<script>
    let autocomplete = new Autocomplete('/autocomplete', 'query');
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may try with camelCase on naming **autoComplete**.

```
    let autoComplete = new Autocomplete('/autocomplete', 'query');
    <input oninput="autoComplete.requestSuggestions();" placeholder="Product search" required type="search" value="">
```

It seems **autocomplete** this word is conflicting with the HTML element on the form there.

Furthermore, camelCase is more a standard naming convention in javascript also.

Answer (score -1):

Move you second script before input.

```
    <script>
    class Autocomplete {
        constructor(path, queryId) {
            this.handler = new XMLHttpRequest();
            this.url = new URL(path, document.location.origin);
            this.query = document.getElementById(queryId);
        }

        requestSuggestions() {
            if(this.query.value.length >= this.query.minLength)
            {
                this.url.searchParams.set(this.query.name, this.query.value);
                this.handler.open('GET', this.url);
                this.handler.onload = this.showSuggestions;
                this.handler.responseType = 'json';
                this.handler.send();
            }
        }

        showSuggestions() {
            let response = this.handler.response;

            if(response.length > 0)
            {
            }
        }
    };

    let autocomplete = new Autocomplete('/autocomplete', 'query');
</script>
<form action="/search" autocomplete="off" method="get">
    <input data-result-empty="Nothing found" id="query" maxlength="64" minlength="3" name="query" oninput="autocomplete.requestSuggestions();" placeholder="Product search" required type="search" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunate, it will not help. I think, the problem with the `this` variable.

Comment: First of all your function is not achievable from HTML, we need to resolve that. If you are able to call your class's method then only `this` will come into the picture.